# Redis Cache Key selection

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis

I am confused about choosing a unique cache key for the profile route of users

for example

```
router.get('/profile/me', auth, async (req, res) => {

// first check that is it available on Redis

// if not execute mongoose query and store this on Redis

  const key = JSON.stringify({
    ...this.getQuery(),
    collection: this.mongooseCollection.name
  });

//assume hashKey: req.user._id

const result = await exec.apply(this, args);
client.hset(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));

// if yes then immediately return from Redis
})
```

I want to cache this route and will clear that cache when we go to these routes

```
router.patch('/profile/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
// clear cache with specific hashKey if response is 200
client.del(hashKey)
})

router.delete('/profile/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
// clear cache with specific hashKey if response is 200
client.del(hashKey)
})
```

But the problem is that what if we want to cache another user's profile and how we know that the user has updated or deleted because we will clear cache when he deletes or updates his profile

for example:

```
router.get('/profile/user/:userId', auth, async (req, res) => {

// first check that is it available on Redis

// if not execute mongoose query and store this on Redis

//WHAT WILL BE hashKey ? req.params.userId OR req.user._id

// if yes then immediately return from Redis
})
```

And how do we clear the cache because we don't have these routes

```
router.patch('/profile/user/:userId', auth, async (req, res) => {
// clear cache with specific hashkey if response is 200
})

router.delete('/profile/user/:userId', auth, async (req, res) => {
// clear cache with specific hashkey if response is 200
})
```

So the question is what should be the hashKey?